# Is it possible to set "access-control-allow-origin" to "none"?

Tags: cors

It might be a stupid question showing that I do not understand CORS, but I will ask it anyway not having found anything about this. I read literally hundreds of question about setting "access-control-allow-origin" to "*", but I would like quite the opposite.

If I want to prevent a site to be "called" or "inserted" ( not sure about the right term) from/in another website, can I set "access-control-allow-origin" to "none" ?
The MDN documentation tells about setting it to "null" (not a good idea) ... Maybe just removing "access-control-allow-origin" will do what I want but this is generating an error, so I was wondering if this could be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; whereas the wildcard (`*`) allows any origin (without credentials), there is no special `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value for disallowing all origins. Moreover, as you already noted, `null` doesn't mean what you want and should never be allowed (because [it's quite insecure](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors#whitelisted-null-origin-value)).

To indicate that the supplied origin isn't allowed, simply do not include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at all in the response.

Comment: Ok, it was not the answer I was hoping for but definitely the one I was expecting :-) Do you have an idea of what organization has the reponsability for defining CORS rules ? IETF ? (Your answer is of course accepted).

Comment: @pierr0t The de facto standard for CORS is controlled by WHATWG. It's part of the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: Ok thanks for that reference !